# Linq query that return IDs that do not match

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables that have Item ID's and I am trying to get a list of ID's that exist in one and not the other.

This is what I have so far.

```
 var misMathcedID = (from a in TableA
                     join b in TableB
                     on a.ItemNumber equals b.ItemNumber
                     where b.ItemNumber == null
                     select a).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry, it returns no values. I have checked manually and there are ids that don't exist in TableB that exist in TableA. TableA has about 30,000 IDs and TableB has about 20,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something similar to this.

```
 var infoQuery = (from a in TableA
 select a.id).Except(from b in tableB select b.id)
```

Comment: No problem Linqs an awesome tool to get to know.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do an `Except` if they are just tables of Ids

```
var result = TableA.Except(TableB);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write an extension method and use it to get the values that exist in one list but not the other:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool NotIn<T>(this T item, IList<T> list)
    {
        return !list.Contains(item);
    }
}

//Example:
List<int> listA = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int> listB = new List<int> { 3, 5, 7, 8 };

var result = listA.Where(x => x.NotIn(listB));
//Output: 1, 2, 4
```

Comment: Nevermind my answer, I didn't know about `Except()`. Use that instead, this is overkill... :D